# How do I find out programmatically which GTK+ theme and engine are being used?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

The Murrine engine hard-codes some behavior that I need to duplicate in my own code, so I need to find out whether the Murrine engine is being used, or some other one. How can I do that? Which config files store this information, and is there an API that I can call?

Comment: Not to invalidate the question, but it sounds ... iffy. Your code for non-themed GTK+ should not, in my opinion, mimic the behavior of the theming engine. What if users don't want that behavior, but really prefer the behavior that all other GTK+ apps use on their system?

Comment: The specific reason why I need this is to paint the keyboard accelerators in menus with the same color as Murrine paints them. I'm pretty certain that the users prefer to have consistent look in all apps.

Comment: The [gtk-theme-switch](http://gna.org/projects/gtk-theme-switch/) code might have something useful.

Answer (score 7):

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html can help you parse some Gtk+ settings. At least reading the theme name is fairly simple:

```
GtkSettings *settings;
gchar *theme_name;
settings = gtk_settings_get_default();
g_object_get(settings, "gtk-theme-name", &theme_name, NULL);
```